# Best way to implement non-mergeable view in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Sometimes we need to get a very particular execution plan from query planner, for example, instead of getting `t2 -> t1 -> t3` join order like in below:

```
create table t1 (c1 int primary key, c2 varchar);
create table t2 (c1 int primary key, c2 varchar);
create table t3 (c1 int primary key, c2 varchar);

explain
select t1.c1, t2.c2
from t1, t2, t3
where t2.c1 = t1.c1
  and t3.c1 = t2.c1
and t2.c2 = 'xxx';

Nested Loop  (cost=0.30..34.65 rows=6 width=36)
  Join Filter: (t2.c1 = t3.c1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.15..33.50 rows=6 width=40)
        ->  Seq Scan on t2  (cost=0.00..25.88 rows=6 width=36)
              Filter: ((c2)::text = 'xxx'::text)
        ->  Index Only Scan using t1_pkey on t1  (cost=0.15..1.27 rows=1 width=4)
              Index Cond: (c1 = t2.c1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using t3_pkey on t3  (cost=0.15..0.18 rows=1 width=4)
        Index Cond: (c1 = t1.c1)
```

our desire is to get `t1 -> t2 -> t3` join, in order to achieve that we use `LATERAL/OFFSET` trick:

```
explain
select t1.c1, t2.c2
from t1,
     lateral (
         select t2.*
         from t2,
              t3
         where t2.c1 = t1.c1
           and t3.c1 = t2.c1
         offset 0) t2
where t2.c2 = 'xxx';

Nested Loop  (cost=0.30..6083.78 rows=1270 width=36)
  ->  Seq Scan on t1  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=4)
  ->  Subquery Scan on t2  (cost=0.30..4.76 rows=1 width=32)
        Filter: ((t2.c2)::text = 'xxx'::text)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.30..4.75 rows=1 width=36)
              ->  Index Scan using t2_pkey on t2 t2_1  (cost=0.15..2.37 rows=1 width=36)
                    Index Cond: (c1 = t1.c1)
              ->  Index Only Scan using t3_pkey on t3  (cost=0.15..2.37 rows=1 width=4)
                    Index Cond: (c1 = t1.c1)
```

unfortunately, using `OFFSET` prevents `PostgreSQL` from pushing down predicates into inline view (as you can see `PostgreSQL` applies `Filter: ((t2.c2)::text = 'xxx'::text)` after joining `t2` and `t3`).

However, there is another option to prevent view merging - use some non-stable function in projection, for example:

```
explain
select t1.c1, t2.c2
from t1,
     lateral (
         select t2.*, random()
         from t2,
              t3
         where t2.c1 = t1.c1
           and t3.c1 = t2.c1
         ) t2
where t2.c2 = 'xxx';

Nested Loop  (cost=0.30..6086.95 rows=1270 width=36)
  ->  Seq Scan on t1  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=4)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.30..4.76 rows=1 width=44)
        ->  Index Scan using t2_pkey on t2  (cost=0.15..2.37 rows=1 width=36)
              Index Cond: (c1 = t1.c1)
              Filter: ((c2)::text = 'xxx'::text)
        ->  Index Only Scan using t3_pkey on t3  (cost=0.15..2.37 rows=1 width=4)
              Index Cond: (c1 = t1.c1)
```

The question is: is there built-in near zero-cost non-stable function in `PostgreSQL` (I believe `random` is not such one)? Or m.b. it is better to implement something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummy() RETURNS varchar AS
$body$
select 'x';
$body$
    LANGUAGE SQL
    STRICT
    COST 1;
```

May I trust `explain(verbose)` in that case?

```
explain (verbose)
select t1.c1, t2.c2
from t1,
     lateral (
         select t2.*, dummy()
         from t2,
              t3
         where t2.c1 = t1.c1
           and t3.c1 = t2.c1
         ) t2
where t2.c2 = 'xxx';

Nested Loop  (cost=0.30..6083.78 rows=1270 width=36)
"  Output: t1.c1, t2.c2"
  ->  Seq Scan on rosatom.t1  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=4)
"        Output: t1.c1, t1.c2"
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.30..4.75 rows=1 width=68)
"        Output: NULL::integer, t2.c2, 'x'::character varying"

                                        ^^^ it seems to get inlined

        ->  Index Scan using t2_pkey on rosatom.t2  (cost=0.15..2.37 rows=1 width=36)
"              Output: t2.c1, t2.c2"
              Index Cond: (t2.c1 = t1.c1)
              Filter: ((t2.c2)::text = 'xxx'::text)
        ->  Index Only Scan using t3_pkey on rosatom.t3  (cost=0.15..2.37 rows=1 width=4)
              Output: t3.c1
              Index Cond: (t3.c1 = t1.c1)
```

Comment: The cheapest function would be a pre-parsed SQL function like `CREATE FUNCTION dummy() RETURNS integer RETURN 1;`. But I don't understand why you want that: simply put `where t2.c2 = 'xxx'` into the subquery.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I can't write such queries directly: ORM's do not support lateral joins, the option is to create a view, which should be non-mergeable. Is there any difference (except word count) between the code you suggested and mine?

Comment: The difference is that it is pre-parsed. Why don't you benchmark them?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe would you mind describing/suggesting how to do that properly on PostgreSQL side? I do believe that is exactly what I'm actually looking for.

Comment: Run the functions 5 million times and see how long it takes.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe well, it turned out there is nothing to benchmark, the syntax you suggested is not supported in `v13` (https://commitfest.postgresql.org/31/2630/), m.b. I will try it later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would start using JOIN's as the new standard, since 30 years ago, ANSI SQL-92.

And when you need data from t1 and t2, there is no need for joining t3: Use EXISTS to check for the condition.

To improve performance, you need EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) to get the plan and the details about the execution. Just EXPLAIN tells you almost nothing, it's just a plan and you don't know if it's a good or bad one. You don't see the issues either.

And about the query above, without details it's not clear what the problem is. You want a specific order in the execution, but it's not clear why and if it would really solve the (unknown) problem.

Comment: I wonder how explain(whatever) can tell which function is better `random()` or `dummy()` in my particular case?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I don't think these functions are your problem nor solution. It's not even clear if there is a problem at all.